# timestamp range query firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The following image is my firebase document, how do i retrieve documents based on date range, is it possible ?
So far i have tried this method but it does not work, any idea how ?

```
allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment')
  ..where('filter', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '6 December 2022 at 08:00:00 UTC+8')
  .where('filter', isLessThanOrEqualTo: '30 December 2022 at 08:00:00 UTC+8');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use something like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment')
    .where('filter', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime(2022, 12, 6)))
    .where('filter', isLessThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime(2022, 12, 30)));
```

Remember to create a proper index on firestore.